# how to create a new variable based on a condition

Tags: r, variables

data file name: toys

Lets say I have the following dataframe

```
ID    Name
1     Green Ball
2     Red Ball
3     Blue Bat
4     Green Bat
5     Blue Ball
6     Ball
7     Bat
```

I would like to add a new variable "Color" by searching the color in the Name.

```
ID    Name           Color
1     Green Ball     Green
2     Red Ball       Red
3     Blue Bat       Blue
4     Green Bat      Green
5     Blue Ball      Blue
6     Ball           Other
7     Bat            Other
```

I have never used R and not sure how to go about doing this. I tried this but no luck.

```
toys$Color <- (
if toys$Name = "Green", Color "Green"
else if toys$Name = "Red", Color "Red"
else if toys$Name = "Blue, Color "Blue"
else toys$Name = "Other"
)
```

I would really appreciate some assistance with this.

Thanks

Comment: Is your actual example Colours, or is that just a hypothetical, and you have a master list of values you want to extract?

Comment: Yes it is Colors. Basically the Name column contains a phrase or description. I want the new Color column to simply search the list of given colors, if the color matches anywhere in the Name column, it should put that color in the Color column. If it finds that there are no matching colors in the Name column, then just output "Other". Does this help?

Comment: Have you checked the solution I posted below?

Answer (score 4):

We can use `str_extract`.  Create a `vector` of all the colors ('col1'), use `str_extract` to get the substrings in 'Name' that match the elements in 'col1' by `paste`ing`the 'col1' as a single string separated by`|`.  Replace the`NA` elements in the output to 'Other' to create the new column 'Color'.

```
library(stringr)
col1 <- c("Green", "Red", "Blue")
v1 <- str_extract(toys$Name, paste(col1, collapse="|"))
v1[is.na(v1)] <- "Other"
toys$Color <- v1
toys
#  ID       Name Color
#1  1 Green Ball Green
#2  2   Red Ball   Red
#3  3   Blue Bat  Blue
#4  4  Green Bat Green
#5  5  Blue Ball  Blue
#6  6       Ball Other
#7  7        Bat Other
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a finite number of colors so you can create a list of those. Then use `str_detect` from the package `stringr`, which you need to install. This function allows you to detect the presence of a pattern (color) in a string. We use a loop to apply this function to each element in `df`.

```
df <- as.data.frame(c("Green Ball", "Ball", "Red Ball", "Blue Bat", "White cake", "Deep Purple"))
colnames(df) <- "Items"
colors <- c("Green", "Red", "Blue", "Purple", "Yellow", "White", "Black", "Pink")

library(stringr)
result <- NULL
for (i in 1:NROW(df)){
  true.false <- str_detect(as.character(df[i,1]), colors)
  col <- ifelse(any(true.false), colors[true.false], "No color")
  result <- c(result, col)
}

df$Colors <- result
df
        Items   Colors
1  Green Ball    Green
2        Ball No color
3    Red Ball      Red
4    Blue Bat     Blue
5  White cake    White
6 Deep Purple   Purple
```

**Alternative:**
You can also use this in the for loop described above.

```
library('stringi')
stri_detect_fixed("Deep Purple", c("Purple", "Blue"))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE
```